# Get value from a custom node, or a connected custom node

Tags: python, node-editor

I would like to design my first blender addon and am therefore a beginner in creation of python addons.

I would like to create my own custom blender node tree.

There is a template (in the text editor) to understand how to create custom nodes and I find this template very helpful.

However I'm now stuck on how can I get the content of a value (a string or a float for example) that is present inside a node?

Is there a simple way to access the inputs and/or outputs of a node added in the node-tree?

[image: nodetree of my projet]

I currently have three classes,

- one class defining the content of the node that add cube
- one class that defines the content of the execute node
- and one class defining the action of the button in the execute node.

How can I get (when i click the execute button) the string of the execute node, and how can I get the float of the node connected to execute (here create cube for example) ?

Is there any documentation or tutorials about adding custom nodes in blender?
Thank you in advance for your help.